# Using MainActivity function inside of service is giving error why?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, nullpointerexception, intentservice

**I'm new in android. I need to use MainActivity function in service to reach service's onstartcommand again**

**What I expect is first service will run because of on create method but because of action is not "ACTION_PLAY" service will run MainActivity.start() function then service start again and I get println("action play working")**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val intent = Intent(this,myService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("action","ACTION_STOP")
    startService(intent)

}

fun start(){
    val intent = Intent(this,myService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("action","ACTION_PLAY")
    startService(intent)
}
```

}

```
class myService: Service() {
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    val action = intent?.getStringExtra("action")
    if (action == "ACTION_PLAY"){
        println("action play working")
    }
    else{
        MainActivity().start()
    }



    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
```

}

**But it gives me this error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.isililkproje, PID: 9526
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.isililkproje.myService@95959e6 with Intent { cmp=com.example.isililkproje/.myService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3314)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
    at com.example.isililkproje.MainActivity.start(MainActivity.kt:28)
    at com.example.isililkproje.myService.onStartCommand(myService.kt:19)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

**Please give me an explanation about this why it's giving error and how can I solve this thank you**

Comment: Never create an instance of an activity yourself. "I need to use MainActivity function in service to reach service's onstartcommand again" -- why do you think that you need it? You are already in your service's `onStartCommand()` function.

Comment: I need to restart onStartCommand() if action != "ACTION_PLAY" and I couldn't find any method and I tried this. Is there any method to restart  onStartCommand()

Comment: "I need to restart onStartCommand() if action != "ACTION_PLAY"" -- you seem convinced of this, but it is unclear why. For example, you could add `performStart()` and `performSomethingOtherThanStart()` functions on `myService`, and have `onStartCommand()` call those functions based on the value of your `Intent` extra. "Is there any method to restart onStartCommand()" -- there is no need to do that. This feels like [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Focus less on your attempted approach and focus more on what the *real* problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Service/FakePlayer) shows a service that is started and stopped by an activity, simulating a music player. It is covered in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.6-CC.pdf). The sample is in Java, as that book is four years old, but it should give you some ideas of how to work with services in Android.